# Issues with conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I recently started learning react and just for practice purpose I am trying to make a login and logout thing, here i am trying to use conditional rendering where I stored my isLoggedIn to a `state` and I add a `h1` for displaying the info whether the user is logged in or not and a `button` to toggle between login and logout

I add a onClick event to a button and changed the state whenever the button is clicked, but somehow it is not working without giving me error, here is my code:

```
class App extends React.Component{
    
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            isLoggedIn: false
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    }
    
    handleClick(){
        return(
            this.setState((prevState) => {
                isLoggedIn: !prevState.isLoggedIn
            })
        )
    }
    
    
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>You Logged {this.state.isLoggedIn ? "In" : "Out"}</h1>
                <button style={{cursor:" pointer"}} onClick={this.handleClick}>Login {this.state.isLoggedIn ? "Out": "In"}</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please share the error ?

Comment: FYI: No need to return from click handlers. `setState` does not return anything, and the button will not do anything with a returned value anyway.

Comment: @PMerlet it isnt throwing any error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't doing what you expect:

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
    isLoggedIn: !prevState.isLoggedIn
})
```

In this syntax the curly braces are denoting a *function*, not an *object*.  Since that function isn't returning anything, the state is being set to nothing.

(Additionally, what that function *does* is unintuitive but still technically valid.  It's [creating a label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67889078/issues-with-conditional-rendering/67889237#comment119996225_67889237) rather than assigning a value.)

Wrap the curly braces to make them an object being returned by the function:

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
    isLoggedIn: !prevState.isLoggedIn
}))
```

**Or** explicitly define the return in the function:

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
    return {
        isLoggedIn: !prevState.isLoggedIn
    };
})
```

Generally the rule with the inline arrow functions is that if the very first token is an open curly brace then that is opening the function body.  If the very first token is not an open curly brace then that is the start of an operation that produces the return value.

---

As an aside, the `return` in the click handler itself is superfluous in this case.  Overall the handler function should just be:

```
handleClick(){
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
        isLoggedIn: !prevState.isLoggedIn
    }));
}
```

Comment: Small addendum: `isLoggedIn: !prevState.isLoggedIn` looks like it should throw an error, since it's not the correct way to assign a variable, but it doesn't that's because it's interpreted as a [`label` expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) and is therefore "valid".

Comment: @David it worked and the explanation was pretty good, I will check this answer as answered